# Как создать шаблон страницы на WP Elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, шаблоны

Всем доброго времени суток! 
Подскажите, не могу понять как добавить свой сверстанный шаблон страницы в тему Elementor. Добавляю страницу с необходимым php template name , но в админке она не отображается.Может кто подсказать в каком направлении копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оставлю ответ для себя на память. Шаблон не добавлялся, так как сайт оказался не на хостинге, а на домашнем сервере с криво подключенной БД. Перенес к себе и все заработало.